# MariaDB slowdowns - How to differentiate symptoms from causes

Tags: php, mariadb

I started working on a 15 year old legacy system recently and we have an issue where our customers at certain times of the day experience crazy slowdowns that usually last from 1 to 10 minutes. The slowdowns usually cause some requests to take 2+ minutes.

The system is running a mix of PHP versions ranging from 5.2 to 7.4 and everything connects to the same MariaDB v10.1.

I've tried implementing all the usual ways to catch whatever is slowing down the system - Monitors, slow query logs, and a bit of profiling where possible. But the issue I'm having is that there's nothing really standing out whenever the system slows down - Every part of the system just grinds to a halt.

Usually when I've faced this problem, the slow query log has been helpful in finding the culprit but when looking at the log for this system nothing really stands out since all the queries that usually work fine also start showing up which makes it difficult to figure out what is the actual problem.

Looking at our monitors there's also not really anything standing out in the amount of requests we're receiving or in any of the servers CPU or Memory usage.

The system is clearly not built for the current scale it's running at and there a couple of quite large tables out out several hundred that are used basically everywhere.
However for 99% of the day everything is running fine so I'm suspecting that we have a few scripts that are locking the main tables for a bit too long, causing this issue.
I'm just at a loss on how to single them out.

What other options do I have to locate the issue - What am I overlooking?

Sidenote; We're using Datadog as our monitoring system and they have a PHP profiler that can run in production.. However it only supports Linux and all of our systems are running on Windows.

Sidenote 2; We have quite a few tasks running in Windows task scheduler, and some of our problems may very well stem from these tasks. However there doesn't seem to be a pattern to the problem. It may happen at 1 and 3 o'clock one day but then nothing for the next couple of days.

Comment: Switch on the slow query report and analyze the results.

Comment: Have you checked start times for a scheduled job? Maybe it's just MySQL doing its housekeeping stuff periodically.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that it is the database, or are you just guessing? You could create a script that has some representative queries of several tables and/or databases and call it through cron or remotely, then either log for later analysis or send an alert so you could attempt to troubleshoot during a slowdown event

Comment: @ChrisHaas It's my best guess. I can see a ton of queries that usually run fine end up in the slow query log. If it was due to network issues I guess most queries should still be operating normally.
Setting up a script that logs access to the major tables sounds like a good way to at least get some insight into what's going on.

Comment: something else running on the server that runs your database?

Comment: not likely connected, but 10.1 is more than 2 years past end of life; consider upgrading to 10.6 or 10.11 so you are getting security fixes.